# Are there any characters that are not allowed/used in regex

Tags: regex, invalid-characters

I have the somehow weird requirement that several regex should be passed as one single string to a jenkins plugin.

They should be entered in one single textfield and I have to split this string in a List of Regex later on.

Now the issue is, I can't think of any way to delimit the regexes in the string so I can later split this string as a character like a `,` could also be considered part of a regex itself.

E.g. if I'd use a `,` for the two regex `"(\d+,?\s+\d{1})\.xls"` and `"\w+\.exe"` :

```
"(\d+,?\s+\d{1})\.xls,\w+\.exe"
```

would be split into 3 regexes: `"(\d+"`, `"?\s+\d{1})\.xls"` and `"\w+\.exe"`
where the first 2 are obviously invalid.

So my actual question is, are there any characters, that can never appear in a regex which I could use to delimit my regexes?

Comment: Use a combination of chars that are invalid as per your regex engine. E.g. `<<++>>` if your engine does not support possessive quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

No, any and all characters can appear in a regex. Use any serialisation format to serialise your *list of strings* into a clearly expressed list format, e.g. **JSON**:

```
["(\\d+", "?\\s+\\d{1})\\.xls", "\\w+\\.exe"]
```

Alternatively CSV or anything else that can express a *list of things* and properly escapes characters used to denote item separators.